# Calling JSF managed bean method with arguments in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF to build a site. I have included [jQuery Gritter (Growl)](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/) notification on my home page. Is it possible to call a managed bean method inside the `before_close:` of `$.gritter.add` function?

The code that I want to use is as follows:

```
<h:body>
    <c:forEach items="#{notificationBean.growlNotificationList}" var="p">
        <script>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'Notification',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'Comment on your staus',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: true, 
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out (milliseconds)
            time: 8000,
            // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply directly to the notification for custom styling
            class_name: 'gritter-light',
            // (function | optional) function called before it closes
            before_close: function(e, manual_close){
                '#{notificationBean.set0ToGrowlToShow(p.notificationID)}'
            }
        });
        /* ]]> */
        </script>
    </c:forEach>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current attempt merely interprets the given EL expression as a value expression and just prints its result immediately during producing the HTML output with the JS code embedded. It's like as if you're using `<h:outputText>`. This is indeed not going to work.

The functional requirement is however understood. The standard JSF API does not offer a ready-to-use solution for this. If you want to stick to standard JSF API, your best bet is to create a hidden form with a hidden command link which you trigger using JavaScript.

Basically,

```
<h:form id="form" style="display:none">
    <h:inputHidden id="id" value="#{notificationBean.notificationID}" />
    <h:commandLink id="command" action="#{notificationBean.set0ToGrowlToShow}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

with

```
$("[id='form:id']").val(#{p.notificationID});    
$("[id='form:command']").click();
```

However, this is pretty clumsy. Consider looking for a 3rd party JSF component or even utility library to achieve the requirement anyway. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has the [`<o:commandScript>`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/o/commandScript.html) component for this. See also its [showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript).

```
<h:form>
    <o:commandScript name="set0ToGrowlToShow" action="#{notificationBean.set0ToGrowlToShow}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
set0ToGrowlToShow(#{p.notificationID});
```

*(please note that this is set as HTTP request parameter, not as action method argument)*

The JSF component library [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) has the [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/remoteCommand.html) for this which is much similar to `<o:commandScript>`. See also its [showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf). Even more, PrimeFaces has a ready-to-use [`<p:growl>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/growl.html) component which does essentially the same as your jQuery plugin! See also its [showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf). Instead of your whole jQuery thing you can just do:

```
<p:growl globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" />
```

and feed it with messages by

```
facesContext.addMessage(null, message);
```

#### See also:

- [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript/)
- [How to pass JavaScript variables as parameters to JSF action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591301/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-as-parameters-to-jsf-action-method)

Comment: Where will I paste the following code `<h:form id="foo" style="display:none">
    <h:commandLink id="bar" action="#{notificationBean.set0ToGrowlToShow(p.notificationID)}"><f:ajax /></h:commandLink>
</h:form>`. Will I place it outside the <script> tag.

Comment: Yes. Are you familiar with basic HTML? Just do rightclick and *view source* in browser. You just have to make sure that the JSF-produced HTML code is [valid](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: getting `Component ID foo has already been found in the view.` in the exception

Comment: That's a different problem unrelated to the concrete question. The answer is basically already in the exception message itself: just don't use the same ID on multiple components.

Comment: Is it because the form with id = foo is generated multiple times inside the forEach?. Is there any work around?

Comment: As said, this is going to be very clumsy. You could add another loop which prints the form with a dynamic ID. You could use a single form with an additional `<h:inputHidden>` whose value you manipulate with jQuery. I've edited the answer with the latter approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that you need to call a java method that runs in the server and you **CANNOT** call it directly.

In your case, I would recommend to use AJAX or have the value read on load of the page and use it (if feasible for you)

Check how you can use [AJAX with Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: OP is aware of this, that's why the question is how to call the managed bean method inside the JavaScript method. By the way, JSF 2 already supports ajax interaction, and there are third party libraries like PrimeFaces and RichFaces that ease ajax and JSF interaction.