# How do I determine the coordinates of a p: dialog on the pe: documentViewer

Tags: html, pdf, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm showing a pdf file on the web with pe: documentViewer.
 I want to add some information (signature information) on the pdf file image. This information can be changed with the p: dialog, and can be added to any of the PDF pages by sliding it anywhere.

In fact, I would like to do the Web Apllication (with smart card) of digital signing in Adobe Reader. My problem is to specify which coordinates to add the signature image on the pdf. This is how I transfer the coordinates to the server. I look forward to your support.

In the following code, how do I send the coordinates of dlg1 on the documentViewer to the server?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    PDF File Upload
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h:inputFile id="uploader" value="#{uploadData.file}"
            validator="#{uploadData.validate}" update="#{uploadData.file}" />

        <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{uploadData.upload}" />

        <p:dialog header="Signature View" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
            <h:outputText value="Signer informations..." />
            <p:commandButton value="Sign" type="button"
                actionListener="#{uploadData.startSign}"
                update="#{uploadData.continueSigning}"
                onclick="PF('dialogEImza').show();" />
        </p:dialog>

        <h:message for="uploader" />
        <p:commandButton value="Sign" type="button"
            onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />

        <h:panelGroup id="pdfPanel">
            <pe:documentViewer id="pdfData" rendered="#{uploadData.uploaded}"
                height="600" locale="tr" value="#{uploadData.obje}"
                encoding="CP1254" />
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:dialog id="dialogEImza" rendered="true"
```

Comment: Generally related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591301/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-as-parameters-to-jsf-action-method

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But, my problem is not to move to the server.
My problem is to create the coordinates of an object(p:dialog) on Pdf(pe:documentViewer).